# WCF NetTcp service throwing error for only one specifc method

Tags: c#, wcf, model-view-controller

I have a WCF Service which used to return results without any errors.

But when I call the below new method, service is throwing error.

```
 [OperationContract]
 IEnumerable<ViewModelClass> GetParameterDetails(int ID, DataType DataType);

[DataContract]
public class ViewModelClass:ParameterBase
{
[DataMember]
 public string Name { get; set; }
 [DataMember]
 public string Source { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(ViewModelClass))]
public class ParameterBase
{
[DataMember]
public string ID{ get; set; }
[DataMember]
public Caluculate Type{ get; set; }
}

In service.cs I have,

 public IEnumerable<ViewModelClass> GetParameterDetails(int ID, DataType DataType)
{
 //logic to build the IEnumerable object.
return IEnumerable<ViewModelClass> object.
```

}

When I run service in debug mode, service.cs method return object is building correctly. But when control is coming back to the client, service is throwing below error:

Description The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:24:59.9989999'. The local IP address and port is [fe80::b970:d9d6:eb18:3099%11]:64559. The remote IP address and port is [fe80::b970:d9d6:eb18:3099%11]:808.

Can anyone please point out the cause for this issue?

**WCF Trace :**

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>262256</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Error">0</SubType><Level>2</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-12-16T02:27:18.0730381Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{4574d886-9e5d-44fa-8c93-b5e905192998}" /><Execution ProcessName="iisexpress" ProcessID="11028" ThreadID="6" /><Channel /><Computer>DTHOTA</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Channels.TcpConnectionResetError.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:24:59.9989999'. The local IP address and port is [fe80::b970:d9d6:eb18:3099%11]:64480. The remote IP address and port is [fe80::b970:d9d6:eb18:3099%11]:808.</Description><AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/29/ROOT-1-130631704283860695</AppDomain><ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/MessageTraceRecord"></ExtendedData><Exception><ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:24:59.9989999'.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ConvertTransferException(SocketException socketException, TimeSpan timeout, Exception originalException, TransferOperation transferOperation, Boolean aborted, String timeoutErrorString, TransferOperation timeoutErrorTransferOperation, SocketConnection socketConnection, TimeSpan remainingTime)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ConvertReceiveException(SocketException socketException, TimeSpan remainingTime)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.Receive(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource.Receive(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel.Receive(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel.TryReceive(TimeSpan timeout, Message&amp;amp; message)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&amp;amp; msgData, Int32 type)
   at WebApplication2.Validation.IManagementService.GetParameterDetails(Int32 ID, DataType DataType)
   at WebApplication2.Validation.ManagementServiceClient.GetParameterDetails(Int32 ID, DataType DataType)
   at WebApplication2._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at ASP.default_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp;amp; completedSynchronously)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus&amp;amp; notificationStatus)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus&amp;amp; notificationStatus)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
   at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:24:59.9989999'. ---&amp;gt; System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</ExceptionString><InnerException><ExceptionType>System.Net.Sockets.SocketException, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host</Message><StackTrace>   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)</ExceptionString><NativeErrorCode>2746</NativeErrorCode></InnerException></Exception></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent>
```

Comment: Is Calculate enum type? If it is you shoud use DataContract and EnumMember attributes on it.

Comment: Calculate is another class which is having DataContract and DataMember attributes.

Comment: Try changing `IEnumerable<ViewModelClass>` to `ViewModelClass[]` and see if that works.

Comment: And remove the line `[KnownType(typeof(ViewModelClass))]` since `ParamaterBase` is not a `ViewModelClass`.

Comment: You can enable  [wcf tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and you'l get detailed server-side exception.

Comment: I tried changing IEnumerable<ViewModelClass> to ViewModelClass[] and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Dima, Above Error description is picked from WCF tracing. I also copied the entire error details in my question above. Apart from that I am not able to see any useful information for this issue in the trace results.

Comment: JRLambert, After changing IEnumerable to array, WCF tracing pointed me to the correct error. Issue was actually related to the calculate class enum property. Database was returning value that is not part of enum declared members.